# Script Not Working When Added to Website (Works in Console)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a jQuery script which will remove all delivery methods that contain the text **"Royal Mail"** if specific products exist within the users cart. This works perfectly when I run it in Google Chrome Console but it does not work when added to my website.

My theory is that this is because the page hasn't generated the elements that I'm targeting yet, however my script is wrapped with `jQuery(document).ready(function(){});`, so should this not handle that issue?

Please see my code below:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var prodname = jQuery(".product-name").text();
        var method1 = jQuery(".shipment-methods li label:eq(0)");
        var method1val = jQuery(".shipment-methods li label:eq(0)").text();
        var method2 = jQuery(".shipment-methods li label:eq(1)");
        var method2val = jQuery(".shipment-methods li label:eq(1)").text();
        var method3 = jQuery(".shipment-methods li label:eq(2)");
        var method3val = jQuery(".shipment-methods li label:eq(2)").text();
        var method4 = jQuery(".shipment-methods li label:eq(3)");
        var method4val = jQuery(".shipment-methods li label:eq(3)").text();
        var method5 = jQuery(".shipment-methods li label:eq(4)");
        var method5val = jQuery(".shipment-methods li label:eq(4)").text();
        var method6 = jQuery(".shipment-methods li label:eq(5)");
        var method6val = jQuery(".shipment-methods li label:eq(5)").text();
        var method7 = jQuery(".shipment-methods li label:eq(6)");
        var method7val = jQuery(".shipment-methods li label:eq(6)").text();
        var method8 = jQuery(".shipment-methods li label:eq(7)");
        var method8val = jQuery(".shipment-methods li label:eq(7)").text();

        if (
            prodname.includes("Kobra HP Spray Paint - ") ||
            prodname.includes("Kobra Low Spray Paint - ") ||
            prodname.includes("Kobra Spray Paint 600ml - ") ||
            prodname.includes("Krome Spray Paint") ||
            prodname.includes("Kobra Big Black Spray Paint") ||
            prodname.includes("Kobra Low Spray Can Cushion") ||
            prodname.includes("Kobra Bombing Pack") ||
            prodname.includes("Spray Paint 5 Pack - Fluorescent") ||
            prodname.includes("Kobra HP x Mr. Serious Pack") ||
            prodname.includes("Kobra Low Spray Paint - 24 Pack") ||
            prodname.includes("Graffiti Starter Pack") ||
            prodname.includes("Mini Bombing Pack") ||
            prodname.includes("Kobra Low Spray Paint - 12 Pack") ||
            prodname.includes("Kobra Low Spray Paint - 18 Pack") ||
            prodname.includes("Kobra Low Spray Paint - 36 Pack") ||
            prodname.includes("Kobra Spray Paint - 12 Pack") ||
            prodname.includes("Kobra Spray Paint - 18 Pack") ||
            prodname.includes("Kobra Spray Paint - 24 Pack") ||
            prodname.includes("Kobra Spray Paint - 36 Pack")
            ) {
            if (method1val.includes("Royal Mail")) {
                method1.closest("li").css("display","none");
            }
            if (method2val.includes("Royal Mail")) {
                method2.closest("li").css("display","none");
            }
            if (method3val.includes("Royal Mail")) {
                method3.closest("li").css("display","none");
            }
            if (method4val.includes("Royal Mail")) {
                method4.closest("li").css("display","none");
            }
            if (method5val.includes("Royal Mail")) {
                method5.closest("li").css("display","none");
            }
            if (method6val.includes("Royal Mail")) {
                method6.closest("li").css("display","none");
            }
            if (method7val.includes("Royal Mail")) {
                method7.closest("li").css("display","none");
            }
            if (method7val.includes("Royal Mail")) {
                method7.closest("li").css("display","none");
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

The script checks if the product name exists within the `product-name` class and then removes the delivery methods if required.

Thank you for any insight you are able to provide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably, you are executing your code before `jQuery` is defined/loaded. Make sure `jQuery` is included in page ***before*** your script is and put your script inside this wrapper:

```js
jQuery.noConflict();
(function( $ ) {
  $(function() {

    // Put your code here, replacing this comment.

  });
})(jQuery);
```

As a side note, inside this wrapper you can safely use `$()` instead of `jQuery()`.

There are other factors that can influence your script not working initially but, most likely, this will do. If it doesn't, you should check your `console log` and let me know of any errors it outputs.

---

### If that doesn't work...

If the above doesn't work it means your page contents are changed by other scripts in your page, after the `$(document).ready()` event is fired. Most commonly, asynchronous calls (`ajax`). In this case, you need to name and store your script (I placed it in a page variable in the example below) and call it after the ajax call returns and runs the `success` function. (There are other ways to store scripts for later use and this one, while simple, is not the safest.)

A very important note, and a common mistake, is that you should remove the `$(document).ready(){}` wrapper from your code because if you try to run it after the document ready already fired, it will do nothing (it will hook to a past event that never runs twice in any page).

The generic example would be:

```js
window.yourVeryUniqueVariableName = function() {
  jQuery.noConflict();
  (function( $ ) {
    $(function() {
      // Put your code here, replacing this comment.
      // Do not wrap your code inside $(document).ready() because that event will 
      // be long fired when your ajax call is successful, so the code will never run!

      // Place here ONLY the contents of  $(document).ready(){} function.
    });
  })(jQuery);
};
```

After that, all you need to do is call the function stored in your custom window variable, from the success function of your ajax call. Generic example:

```js
$.ajax('url_here',{
  success:function(response){
    // response variable holds the returned response from the ajaxURL. 
    // parse it as you please.

    // after all parsing, run your function, from the variable in window Object:
    window.yourVeryUniqueVariableName();
  }
})
```

Important: You should not replace the contents of success function of the ajax call, but add to it.

Also, please note populating the `window` object with custom variables could hardly be considered good practice and is prone to namespace collisions with code from other people using the same unhealthy technique. But I guess learning safe practices for storing code in page should be the subject of another great question. I did it this way here as it was quick, dirty and would get your code run at the proper time.

Comment: Hey man, thank you for your answer but this didn't work and the console doesn't show any errors. This one's really bugging me, I've written quite a lot of scripts with jQuery and I've never had this issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Additionally, the code is in the HTML body end so should run after everything has loaded. Should I perphaps add a delay to the entire code block or something? Thank you.

Comment: I think I've just worked out the issue. The checkout page is Ajax and has multiple sections load for the same URL. The script is probably loading when the delivery methods aren't showing and therefore when the delivery methods do appear on screen, the script has already loaded. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I was going to suggest that your html must be changing after page is ready, and to ask you about any async calls the page might be making. In that case you need to store your script as a function inside a page variable and call it on `.success()` of `.ajax()`. Doing it with a setTimeout is bad, because it will fail, should your `ajax` call take longer than the timeout.

Comment: This sounds interesting as I'm having big trouble working out how to do this. Could you link me to any more information on using `.success()` please which is relevant to this? Thank you so much,

Comment: Updated answer, should get you going. Save your code in a variable and call it from the success function of your ajax call, without replacing the current contents of the success function. Add to it.

Comment: You're awesome :)